# sudden (unintended) auto scrolling when hovering on an element

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

a sudden scrolling takes effect simultaneously with hovering on an element. What confuses me more is that it does not happen every time I hover over the element but just occasionally or maybe there is a specific scrolling position that I can't see yet.

the problem appeared after I added the upper triangle part with pseudo-element and handled it with a transition to move from right to left.

problem is illustrated in the GIF picture below.

any help please, thanks in advance.

```css
/* Main Heading */
h2.main-heading {
  width: fit-content;
  padding: var(--mainPadding);
  margin: auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 27px;
  border: solid 3px black;
  position: relative;
  transition-property: color, border-color;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  margin-bottom: var(--sectionMarginPadding);
  z-index: 3;
}

h2.main-heading:hover {
  border-color: white;
  color: white;
}

h2.main-heading::before,
h2.main-heading::after {
  content: "";
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: var(--mainColor);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
  transition-property: left, right, width, height, border-radius;
  transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s, 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0, 0, 0.5s;
}
h2.main-heading::before {
  left: -37px;
}
h2.main-heading::after {
  right: -37px;
}

h2.main-heading:hover::before,
h2.main-heading:hover::after {
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
  height: calc(100% + 1px);
  border-radius: 0;
}
h2.main-heading:hover::before {
  left: 0;
}
h2.main-heading:hover::after {
  right: 0;
}

/* **************************************** Variables ***************************************** */
:root {
  --mainPadding: 17px;
  --mainMargin: 30px;
  --sectionMarginPadding: 70px;
  --mainColor: #953553; /* #2196f3 */
  --grayC: #ccc;
  --landingColor: #ececec;
  --pTextColor: #777;
}

/* **************************************** Global Rules ***************************************** */
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Cairo", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  /* background-color: #ddd; */
  padding-left: var(--mainPadding);
  padding-right: var(--mainPadding);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  /* width: var(--containerWidth); */
}


/* *********************************** Features *********************************** */
.features {
  padding: var(--sectionMarginPadding) 0;
}

.features .content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(270px, 1fr));
  gap: var(--mainMargin);
}

.features .content .feature {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid 1px var(--grayC);
  padding-bottom: var(--mainMargin);
}

.features .content .feature .image::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-color: transparent transparent white transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 0px 171px 303px;
  z-index: 2;
  transition-property: border-width;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.features .content .feature:hover .image::before {
  border-width: 171px 500px 171px 0;
}

.features .content .feature .image {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.features .content .feature .image::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.features .content .feature img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(1) .image::after {
  background-color: var(--mainColor);
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(1) h3::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -17px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 80%;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: var(--mainColor);
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(2) .image::after {
  background-color: #009788;
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(2) h3::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -17px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 80%;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: #009788;
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(3) .image::after {
  background-color: #03a9f5;
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(3) h3::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -17px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 80%;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: #03a9f5;
}

.features .content .feature .text h3 {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: var(--mainMargin) auto;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.features .content .feature .text p {
  padding: var(--mainPadding);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: var(--pTextColor);
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.features .content .feature .text a {
  display: block;
  padding: calc(var(--mainPadding) - 7px) var(--mainPadding);
  text-decoration: none;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: auto;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: solid 3px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition-property: color;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.features .content .feature .text a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  height: calc(100% + 10px);
  width: 0%;
  z-index: -1;
  transition-property: width;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.features .content .feature:hover .text a::after {
  width: calc(100% + 10px);
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(1) .text a {
  color: var(--mainColor);
  border-color: var(--mainColor);
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(2) .text a {
  color: #009788;
  border-color: #009788;
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(3) .text a {
  color: #03a9f5;
  border-color: #03a9f5;
}

.features .content .feature:hover .text a {
  color: white;
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(1) .text a::after {
  background-color: var(--mainColor);
}
.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(2) .text a::after {
  background-color: #009788;
}
.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(3) .text a::after {
  background-color: #03a9f5;
}
```

```html
<section class="features container">
      <h2 class="main-heading">features</h2>
      <div class="content">
        <article class="feature">
          <div class="image">
            <img src="https://www.johnacademy.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/O1-DIPLOMA-IN-SEO-AND-DIGITAL-MARKETING-2.jpg" alt="feature-01" />
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <h3>quality</h3>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae
              quaerat ipsam earum sit ex.
            </p>
            <a href="#">more</a>
          </div>
        </article>
        <article class="feature">
          <div class="image">
            <img src="https://www.statnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/AdobeStock_176822080-768x432.jpeg" alt="feature-02" />
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <h3>time</h3>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae
              quaerat ipsam earum sit ex.
            </p>
            <a href="#">more</a>
          </div>
        </article>
        <article class="feature">
          <div class="image">
            <img src="https://wp.inews.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/wood-3157395-e1528392231169.jpg?resize=640,360&strip=all&quality=90" alt="feature-03" />
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <h3>passion</h3>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae
              quaerat ipsam earum sit ex.
            </p>
            <a href="#">more</a>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    </section>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

i think position absolute was the problem so i changed it to relative,  it is broken when the page gets too small or too big but managing that is very easy so i believe you can do that your self(use breakPoints

```css
/* Main Heading */
h2.main-heading {
  width: fit-content;
  padding: var(--mainPadding);
  margin: auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 27px;
  border: solid 3px black;
  position: relative;
  transition-property: color, border-color;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  margin-bottom: var(--sectionMarginPadding);
  z-index: 3;
}

h2.main-heading:hover {
  border-color: white;
  color: white;
}

h2.main-heading::before,
h2.main-heading::after {
  content: "";
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: var(--mainColor);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
  transition-property: left, right, width, height, border-radius;
  transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s, 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0, 0, 0.5s;
}
h2.main-heading::before {
  left: -37px;
}
h2.main-heading::after {
  right: -37px;
}

h2.main-heading:hover::before,
h2.main-heading:hover::after {
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
  height: calc(100% + 1px);
  border-radius: 0;
}
h2.main-heading:hover::before {
  left: 0;
}
h2.main-heading:hover::after {
  right: 0;
}

/* **************************************** Variables ***************************************** */
:root {
  --mainPadding: 17px;
  --mainMargin: 30px;
  --sectionMarginPadding: 70px;
  --mainColor: #953553; /* #2196f3 */
  --grayC: #ccc;
  --landingColor: #ececec;
  --pTextColor: #777;
}

/* **************************************** Global Rules ***************************************** */
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Cairo", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  /* background-color: #ddd; */
  padding-left: var(--mainPadding);
  padding-right: var(--mainPadding);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  /* width: var(--containerWidth); */
}


/* *********************************** Features *********************************** */
.features {
  padding: var(--sectionMarginPadding) 0;
}

.features .content {
  display: grid;

  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(270px, 1fr));
  gap: var(--mainMargin);
}

.features .content .feature {
  overflow: hidden;

  border: solid 1px var(--grayC);
  padding-bottom: var(--mainMargin);
}

.features .content .feature .image::before {
  content: "";
  position: relative !important;
  bottom: -90px;
  right: 30px;
  border-color: transparent transparent white transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 10px 171px 450px;
  z-index: 2;
  transition-property: border-width;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.features .content .feature:hover .image::before {
  border-width: 171px 500px 171px 0;
}


.features .content .feature .image {

  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -2;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.features .content .feature .image::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.features .content .feature img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(1) .image::after {
  background-color: var(--mainColor);
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(1) h3::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -17px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 80%;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: var(--mainColor);
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(2) .image::after {
  background-color: #009788;
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(2) h3::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -17px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 80%;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: #009788;
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(3) .image::after {
  background-color: #03a9f5;
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(3) h3::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -17px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 80%;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: #03a9f5;
}

.features .content .feature .text h3 {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: var(--mainMargin) auto;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.features .content .feature .text p {
  padding: var(--mainPadding);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: var(--pTextColor);
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.features .content .feature .text a {
  display: block;
  padding: calc(var(--mainPadding) - 7px) var(--mainPadding);
  text-decoration: none;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: auto;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: solid 3px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition-property: color;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.features .content .feature .text a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  height: calc(100% + 10px);
  width: 0%;
  z-index: -1;
  transition-property: width;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.features .content .feature:hover .text a::after {
  width: calc(100% + 10px);
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(1) .text a {
  color: var(--mainColor);
  border-color: var(--mainColor);
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(2) .text a {
  color: #009788;
  border-color: #009788;
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(3) .text a {
  color: #03a9f5;
  border-color: #03a9f5;
}

.features .content .feature:hover .text a {
  color: white;
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(1) .text a::after {
  background-color: var(--mainColor);
}
.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(2) .text a::after {
  background-color: #009788;
}
.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(3) .text a::after {
  background-color: #03a9f5;
}
```

```html
<section class="features container">
    <h2 class="main-heading">features</h2>
    <div class="content">
      <article class="feature">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://www.johnacademy.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/O1-DIPLOMA-IN-SEO-AND-DIGITAL-MARKETING-2.jpg" alt="feature-01" />
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <h3>quality</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae
            quaerat ipsam earum sit ex.
          </p>
          <a href="#">more</a>
        </div>
      </article>
      <article class="feature">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://www.statnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/AdobeStock_176822080-768x432.jpeg" alt="feature-02" />
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <h3>time</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae
            quaerat ipsam earum sit ex.
          </p>
          <a href="#">more</a>
        </div>
      </article>
      <article class="feature">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://wp.inews.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/wood-3157395-e1528392231169.jpg?resize=640,360&strip=all&quality=90" alt="feature-03" />
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <h3>passion</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae
            quaerat ipsam earum sit ex.
          </p>
          <a href="#">more</a>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </section>
```

)

Comment: could you please offer an explanation for why the absolute position causes this?

Comment: to be honest i don't know, still trying to figure it out. i had another idea that instead of (::before) we use a position absolute container so its styles doesn't effect its parent. Do you have any idea?

Comment: sorry, no idea on this specific solution but I found another by using clip-path property and still using the pseud-element

Answer (score 1):

so i think i found out what is the problem, so when we apply border-width the element that we are applying it to is constantly moving so when you made the top border width to a high number i think that made the whole element expand so it made it move

```css
/* Main Heading */
h2.main-heading {
  width: fit-content;
  padding: var(--mainPadding);
  margin: auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 27px;
  border: solid 3px black;
  position: relative;
  transition-property: color, border-color;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  margin-bottom: var(--sectionMarginPadding);
  z-index: 3;
}

h2.main-heading:hover {
  border-color: white;
  color: white;
}

h2.main-heading::before,
h2.main-heading::after {
  content: "";
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: var(--mainColor);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
  transition-property: left, right, width, height, border-radius;
  transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s, 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0, 0, 0.5s;
}
h2.main-heading::before {
  left: -37px;
}
h2.main-heading::after {
  right: -37px;
}

h2.main-heading:hover::before,
h2.main-heading:hover::after {
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
  height: calc(100% + 1px);
  border-radius: 0;
}
h2.main-heading:hover::before {
  left: 0;
}
h2.main-heading:hover::after {
  right: 0;
}

/* **************************************** Variables ***************************************** */
:root {
  --mainPadding: 17px;
  --mainMargin: 30px;
  --sectionMarginPadding: 70px;
  --mainColor: #953553; /* #2196f3 */
  --grayC: #ccc;
  --landingColor: #ececec;
  --pTextColor: #777;
}

/* **************************************** Global Rules ***************************************** */
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Cairo", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  /* background-color: #ddd; */
  padding-left: var(--mainPadding);
  padding-right: var(--mainPadding);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  /* width: var(--containerWidth); */
}


/* *********************************** Features *********************************** */
.features {
  padding: var(--sectionMarginPadding) 0;
}

.features .content {
  display: grid;

  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(270px, 1fr));
  gap: var(--mainMargin);
}

.features .content .feature  {
  overflow: hidden;
 box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 1px var(--grayC);
  padding-bottom: var(--mainMargin);
}
.features .content .feature .image::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-color: transparent transparent white transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 0px 171px 303px;
  z-index: 2;
  transition-property: border-width;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.features .content .feature:hover .image::before {
  border-width: 0px 500px 171px 0;
}
.features .content .feature .image {

  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -2;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.features .content .feature .image::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.features .content .feature img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(1) .image::after {
  background-color: var(--mainColor);
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(1) h3::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -17px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 80%;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: var(--mainColor);
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(2) .image::after {
  background-color: #009788;
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(2) h3::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -17px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 80%;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: #009788;
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(3) .image::after {
  background-color: #03a9f5;
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(3) h3::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -17px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 80%;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: #03a9f5;
}

.features .content .feature .text h3 {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: var(--mainMargin) auto;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.features .content .feature .text p {
  padding: var(--mainPadding);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: var(--pTextColor);
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.features .content .feature .text a {
  display: block;
  padding: calc(var(--mainPadding) - 7px) var(--mainPadding);
  text-decoration: none;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: auto;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: solid 3px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition-property: color;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.features .content .feature .text a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  height: calc(100% + 10px);
  width: 0%;
  z-index: -1;
  transition-property: width;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.features .content .feature:hover .text a::after {
  width: calc(100% + 10px);
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(1) .text a {
  color: var(--mainColor);
  border-color: var(--mainColor);
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(2) .text a {
  color: #009788;
  border-color: #009788;
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(3) .text a {
  color: #03a9f5;
  border-color: #03a9f5;
}

.features .content .feature:hover .text a {
  color: white;
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(1) .text a::after {
  background-color: var(--mainColor);
}
.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(2) .text a::after {
  background-color: #009788;
}
.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(3) .text a::after {
  background-color: #03a9f5;
}
```

```html
<section class="features container">
    <h2 class="main-heading">features</h2>
    <div class="content">
      <article class="feature">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://www.johnacademy.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/O1-DIPLOMA-IN-SEO-AND-DIGITAL-MARKETING-2.jpg" alt="feature-01" />
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <h3>quality</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae
            quaerat ipsam earum sit ex.
          </p>
          <a href="#">more</a>
        </div>
      </article>
      <article class="feature">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://www.statnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/AdobeStock_176822080-768x432.jpeg" alt="feature-02" />
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <h3>time</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae
            quaerat ipsam earum sit ex.
          </p>
          <a href="#">more</a>
        </div>
      </article>
      <article class="feature">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="https://wp.inews.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/wood-3157395-e1528392231169.jpg?resize=640,360&strip=all&quality=90" alt="feature-03" />
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <h3>passion</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae
            quaerat ipsam earum sit ex.
          </p>
          <a href="#">more</a>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </section>
```

i just removed the top border width :
border-width: 0px 500px 171px 0;

Comment: I suspected that, but it was required to have the final shape that I want...Actually, I found a solution and I'll share it in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

we can get rid of the hassle of making the shape with borders and make it with clip-path property using the polygon shape function (I also made the design responsive, but the code snippet square screen is not taken under consideration, please open on full page display to see the result):

```css
/* **************************************** Variables ***************************************** */
:root {
  --mainPadding: 17px;
  --mainMargin: 30px;
  --sectionMarginPadding: 70px;
  --mainColor: #953553; /* #2196f3 */
  --grayC: #ccc;
  --landingColor: #ececec;
  --pTextColor: #777;
}

/* **************************************** Global Rules ***************************************** */
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Cairo", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  /* background-color: #ddd; */
  padding-left: var(--mainPadding);
  padding-right: var(--mainPadding);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  /* width: var(--containerWidth); */
}

/* ****************************** Screen Different Resolutions ****************************** */
/* extra small */
@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
  /* .other-links {
    width: calc(575px - 17px * 2);
  } */
}
/* small */
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    width: 561px;
  }

  /* .other-links {
    width: 561px;
  } */
}
/* medium */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 748px;
  }

  /* .other-links {
    width: 748px;
  } */
}
/* large */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 967px;
  }

  /* .other-links {
    width: 967px;
  } */
}
/* extra large */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }

  /* .other-links {
    width: 1170px;
  } */
}

/* *********************************** Components *********************************** */
/* Main Heading */
h2.main-heading {
  width: fit-content;
  padding: var(--mainPadding);
  margin: auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 27px;
  border: solid 3px black;
  position: relative;
  transition-property: color, border-color;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  margin-bottom: var(--sectionMarginPadding);
  z-index: 3;
}

h2.main-heading:hover {
  border-color: white;
  color: white;
}

h2.main-heading::before,
h2.main-heading::after {
  content: "";
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: var(--mainColor);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
  transition-property: left, right, width, height, border-radius;
  transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s, 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 0, 0, 0.5s;
}
h2.main-heading::before {
  left: -37px;
}
h2.main-heading::after {
  right: -37px;
}

h2.main-heading:hover::before,
h2.main-heading:hover::after {
  width: calc(50% + 1px);
  height: calc(100% + 1px);
  border-radius: 0;
}
h2.main-heading:hover::before {
  left: 0;
}
h2.main-heading:hover::after {
  right: 0;
}

/* *********************************** Features *********************************** */
.features {
  padding-top: var(--sectionMarginPadding);
  padding-bottom: var(--sectionMarginPadding);
}

.features .content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(270px, 1fr));
  gap: var(--mainMargin);
}

.features .content .feature {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid 1px var(--grayC);
  padding-bottom: var(--mainMargin);
}

.features .content .feature .image::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  right: -2px;
  width: 102%;
  height: 310px;
  background-color: white;
  clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 47%, 100% 100%);
  z-index: 2;
  transition-property: clip-path;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.features .content .feature:hover .image::before {
  clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 77%, 100% 100%);
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .features .content .feature .image::before {
    clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 7%, 100% 100%);
  }
  .features .content .feature:hover .image::before {
    clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 47%, 100% 100%);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .features .content .feature .image::before {
    clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 100% 50%, 100% 100%);
  }
  .features .content .feature:hover .image::before {
    clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 77%, 100% 100%);
  }
}

.features .content .feature .image {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.features .content .feature .image::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.features .content .feature img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(1) .image::after {
  background-color: var(--mainColor);
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(1) h3::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -17px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 80%;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: var(--mainColor);
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(2) .image::after {
  background-color: #009788;
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(2) h3::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -17px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 80%;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: #009788;
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(3) .image::after {
  background-color: #03a9f5;
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(3) h3::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -17px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 80%;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: #03a9f5;
}

.features .content .feature .text h3 {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: var(--mainMargin) auto;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.features .content .feature .text p {
  padding: var(--mainPadding);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: var(--pTextColor);
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.features .content .feature .text a {
  display: block;
  padding: calc(var(--mainPadding) - 7px) var(--mainPadding);
  text-decoration: none;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: auto;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: solid 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition-property: color;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.features .content .feature .text a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -7px;
  bottom: -7px;
  right: 100px;
  /* height: calc(100% + 10px);
  width: 0%; */
  z-index: -1;
  transition-property: right;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.features .content .feature:hover .text a::after {
  /* width: calc(100% + 10px); */
  right: -7px;
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(1) .text a {
  color: var(--mainColor);
  border-color: var(--mainColor);
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(2) .text a {
  color: #009788;
  border-color: #009788;
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(3) .text a {
  color: #03a9f5;
  border-color: #03a9f5;
}

.features .content .feature:hover .text a {
  color: white;
}

.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(1) .text a::after {
  background-color: var(--mainColor);
}
.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(2) .text a::after {
  background-color: #009788;
}
.features .content .feature:nth-of-type(3) .text a::after {
  background-color: #03a9f5;
}
```

```html
<!------------------------------------- Features ------------------------------------->
    <section class="features container">
      <h2 class="main-heading">features</h2>
      <div class="content">
        <article class="feature">
          <div class="image">
            <img src="https://www.johnacademy.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/O1-DIPLOMA-IN-SEO-AND-DIGITAL-MARKETING-2.jpg" alt="feature-01" />
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <h3>quality</h3>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae
              quaerat ipsam earum sit ex.
            </p>
            <a href="#">more</a>
          </div>
        </article>
        <article class="feature">
          <div class="image">
            <img src="https://www.statnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/AdobeStock_176822080-768x432.jpeg" alt="feature-02" />
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <h3>time</h3>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae
              quaerat ipsam earum sit ex.
            </p>
            <a href="#">more</a>
          </div>
        </article>
        <article class="feature">
          <div class="image">
            <img src="https://wp.inews.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/wood-3157395-e1528392231169.jpg?resize=640,360&strip=all&quality=90" alt="feature-03" />
          </div>
          <div class="text">
            <h3>passion</h3>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae
              quaerat ipsam earum sit ex.
            </p>
            <a href="#">more</a>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    </section>
```